# Scraping with Cheerio

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, cheerio

I'm writing a scraper to obtain psp iso files to download based on the rating. I'm having a difficult time targeting each rating. How can I grab this element? I've included a snapshot for reference. The rating element is within a `tr td` tag.

```
var request = require('request'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  fs = require('fs');

var url = 'http://goo.gl/cc4HRc',
  pspGames = [];

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.gamelist', 'td').each(function () {
      var links = $(this).attr('href');
      pspGames.push(links);
    });
   }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link, it looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="index gamelist" title="Corpse Party - Book of Shadows (Japan) ISO Info and Download" href="/Sony_Playstation_Portable_ISOs/Corpse_Party_-_Book_of_Shadows_(Japan)/158702">Corpse Party - Book of Shadows (Japan)</a>
  </td>
  <td align="center">4.9504</td>
</tr>
```

You should just do: `$('.gamelist').each(`

Comment: I was a little hung up on if my selector was correct. How can I encapsulate that rating 4.9504? Is this an attribute?

Comment: $(this).parents('tr').find('td').last().html()

Comment: I would've never have gotten that. I was reading the docs and couldn't find anything similar to this case. For future reference, how did you come up with that? Appreciate your help by the way. Also, why did you just target ```gamelist``` instead of ```.gamelist, td```.

Comment: jQuery :) Just think in terms of a DOM tree, parents, find, last, all relates back to where you are at the moment. Read up on jQuery selectors and it will be easier next time.

Comment: God, I hope so. I'll make you proud next time! haha

Comment: It's best to keep it simple in this case, what you are looking for is attribute value href, which is attached to the a. You need to grab all the anchors related to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you were going to store the rating, but maybe something like this will help:

```
$('.gamelist').each(function () {
    var link = $(this.attr('href'));
    var rating = $(this).parent().siblings().first().text();
    pspGames.push({"link": link, "rating": rating});
});
```

Comment: More often than not I'll have to use a hash, parse to float and write a conditional to check if it's above a specific rating and then append. I need to read up on parent(). Nicely done!